# Parsing Nested Using Pyspark Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am having a nested json file with a structure like this:

```
    {
        "value": {
            "employee": {
                 "employeeid": "1234",
                "employeename": "ABCD",
                 "contactNumber": [
                            {
                                "type": "Work",

                                "phoneNumber": "1234567890"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Home",

                                "phoneNumber": "0987654321"
                            }
                        ] }}}
```

I need to flatten this array present in json and write to a table in Amazon RDS using glue. I have tried creating the following piece:

```
 import sys
    from awsglue.transforms import *
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    from awsglue.job import Job
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
    datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "test", table_name = "employee", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
    relationalized_json = datasource0.relationalize(root_table_name = "root", staging_path = args["TempDir"])
    root_df = relationalized_json.select('root')
    applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = root_df, mappings= [("`value.employee.employeeid`","string", "employeeid","string"),("`value.employee.employeename`","string", "employeename","string"), ("`value.employee.employeename.contactNumber.value.type`","string", "type","string"),("`value.employee.employeename.contactNumber.value.phoneNumber`","string", "phoneNumber","string")]transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
    datasink1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = applymapping1, catalog_connection = "test", connection_options = {"dbtable": "employee", "database": "testdb"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink1")
```

It is populating values for all the columns except type and phone number.
Type and phone number are populated as null.
Please let me know the issue here?

Comment: the problem is that spark sees the Employee map to have values of different data types, `"1234"` and `"ABCD"` are strings and for `contactNumber`, the value's type is `arraytype(maptype(stringtype(),stringtype()))`. u could use explode from_json on contactNumber to pasrse it if the input was `"""[{"type": "Work","phoneNumber": "1234567890"},{"type": "Home","phoneNumber": "0987654321"}]"""`

Comment: basically your json requires work on contactNumber before loading to spark or after.

Comment: Hi Murtaza, Can you please add more details or a sample code snippet?

Comment: check my post and let me know if you have any question

Comment: Murtaza: Please check my post I am getting mismatch error